# Algorithm for selecting subset satisfying conditions

Tags: algorithm, subset

I have some customer references, and each reference has some properties:

1. When it was added.
2. Solution (for example HR, health care, controlling, etc).
3. Industry (for example transport, energy, electronics, etc).
4. Whether it comes from a strong brand.
5. Region (for example country/continent).

Now I would like to select a subset of the references to show on my homepage. The references should be selected randomly, so that they are different every time someone visits my home page. At the same time, I would like the selected references to fulfill some conditions:

1. Recently added references have higher probability of being selected.
2. There should be a variety in solutions.
3. There should be a variety in industries.
4. There should be a variety in whether the references come from strong brands.
5. There should be a variety in region.

How can I create such a selection algorithm?

## Edit 2018-09-08

### Database structure

```
| Column           | Type   | Key type    |
|------------------|--------|-------------|
| ReferenceId      | int    | Primary key |
| AuthorName       | string |             |
| OrganisationName | string |             |
| Content          | string |             |
| AddedDate        | date   |             |
| SolutionId       | int    | Foreign key |
| IndustryId       | int    | Foreign key |
| BrandIsStrong    | bool   |             |
| RegionId         | int    | Foreign key |
```

### Solution ideas

#### 1. Assigning weights

General idea: Assign weights to the references and select references based on their combined weight. For example like this:

1. Assign a weight `DateWeight` to each reference. The older the reference, the lower the weight.
2. For each solution, go through each reference belonging to that solution in a random order, assigning to each reference a weight `SolutionWeight`. For each iteration, decrease the assigned weight. In the end there will be one reference in each solution with a high `SolutionWeight`, one reference with a slightly lower `SolutionWeight`, etc. If you now go through all references ordered by decreasing `SolutionWeight`, the variation in solution will be great.
3. Do as in step 2, but for industry instead of solution, and let's call the weight `IndustryWeight` instead of `SolutionWeight`.
4. Do as in step 2, but for strong brand vs. not strong brand instead of solution, and let's call the weight `BrandWeight` instead of `SolutionWeight`.
5. Do as in step 2, but for region instead of solution, and let's call the weight `RegionWeight` instead of `SolutionWeight`.
6. Each reference now has 5 weights. These should be combined into one (for example by addition or multiplication), and then `n` references are selected to be shown on the home page. This could for example be done by:

   1. Selecting the references with the highest combined weight.
   2. An iterative process where one reference is selected in each iteration, and each reference's probability of being selected is relative to its combined weight.

#### 2. Iterative selection

General idea: Iterate through each constraint, selecting one reference at a time.

1. Let `Unselected` be the set of references that have not been selected.
2. Select the most recent reference in `Unselected`.
3. For each solution, select a random reference in `Unselected`, belonging to that solution.
4. For each industry, select a random reference in `Unselected`, belonging to that industry.
5. Select one reference from a strong brand and one reference that is not from a strong brand.
6. For each region, select a random reference in `Unselected`, belonging to that region.
7. Repeat steps 2 to 6 until `n` references have been selected.

A drawback with this solution is if one of the constraints contains many options (for example if the number of different industires is larger than `n`). Then the process would stop before even one iteration had been completed.

#### 3. Adjusting weights

General idea: For each reference that is selected, decrease the weight assigned to references with the same properties as the selected reference.

1. Assign the same weight to each reference.
2. Select a reference using a weighted random selection.
3. Decrease the weight of all references with the same solution as the selected reference.
4. Decrease the weight of all references with the same industry as the selected reference.
5. If the selected reference is from a strong brand, decrease the weight of all references from strong brands. If the selected reference is not from a strong brand, decrease the weight of all references that are not from strong brands.
6. Decrease the weight of all references with the same region as the selected reference.
7. Repeat steps 2 to 7 until `n` references have been selected.

Comment: Could you post some code showing your data structure, and what you tried so far?

Comment: @AlexM See my updated question.

Comment: Are you able to quantify what you mean by `There should be a variety in [...]`? Do you know how much of a compromise you are willing to make when your desired set of selected references (say of sier `n`) is smaller than the cardinality of one of your columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it mostly lies in how you quantify an acceptable solution, and how you define constraints such as `There should be a variety in [...]`. You also have to decide what to do when your data are heavily correlated: for instance, if most "strong brand" references come from one "industry", then since you want many industries to be represented you'll have a small proportion of "strong brand" elements in your set. In that case you will not be able to have both.

Let us assume you need to display `n` items on your page. This is an external constraint, probably defined by the size of the web element containing the list of items; the rest of the constraints are chosen by you.

Jump to *tl;dr* section at the bottom to skip details.

### Solution 1: cheap and (generally) effective: 100% random

You could simply choose `n` references at random, and let the universe decide which items make it to your page. If your data are more or less evenly spread across the various columns, and if `n` is "large enough", you'll get good enough data most of the time. This also makes your code very easily maintainable/upgradeable in case you need a quick implementation, so you can come back to it later when you have a better algorithm.

Now this does not address the

> Recently added references have higher probability of being selected

part, so we can do a little bit better

### Solution 2: not 100% random

This is a slightly modified version of the first solution. In this one, you iterate along your dataset, starting with the most recent "ReferenceId" and following decreasing order of "ReferenceId". Each item has a probability `p` of being chosen, chosen such that the `n` elements generally lie within the `N` most recent elements of your dataset. If you reach the bottom before having chosen `n` elements, just start from the top again (or increase `p`).

In Java, this would look like:

```
for (Object item : items) {
    if (random.nextDouble() < p) {
        result.add(item);
    }
    if (result.size() == n) {
        break;
    }
}
```

However if your data is **not** evenly distributed (which may be the case since you're asking this question), you cannot rely on randomness only to generate your set of items. Before moving on to solution 3, do check whether this solution works for you or not. If not,

### Solution 3: formulate constraints and try to satisfy them, greedy method

What you have to do now is to define what it means for a set of size `n` to meet the requirements regarding your global dataset.

You have to know that since you're tweaking the odds of each particular item of being chosen in the final set, you may not be able to truly have

> they are different every time someone visits my home page

To be really sure of this, picture an example where one of the "regions" is represented by only one item in the whole dataset: it will most likely always be in the final selected subset since you want to force diversity. There is also the fact that since you privilege recently added references, your data distribution will more closely reflect that of the most recent entries.

So now you're at peace with not always necessarily having *true* randomness **and** uniform representation, let's formulate constraints. A constraint for a column can be in the form of "I would like to have at least `n/10` distinct elements from this column in the final subset". You evaluate the state of a constraint as "satisfied" or "unsatisfied" with a function `(S, n, k) -> {true, false}` where:

- `S` is the current set of selected items
- `n` is the desired size for the selected items
- `k` is the cardinality of the column

saying "given the current subset of elements, is this constraint satisfied yet?". You can also evaluate whether an element contributes to satisfying the constraint, saying "given the current subset of elements, are we closer to satisfying this constraint if we add this item?".

Iterate just like in solution 2 above, and keep the randomness for each element, but also add a check for constraint satisfaction, with a `Set` of constraints. Once a constraint is satisfied, remove it from the set of constraints.

Without implementation details you would get something like:

```
for (Object item : items) {
    // every item still has some probability of being chosen or not
    if (random.nextDouble() < p && helpsSatsfyAtLeastOne(remainingConstraints, item, result, n)) {
        result.add(item);                       
    }
    for (/* Appropriate data structure */ constraint : remainingConstraints) {
        if (constraint.isSatisfied(result, n)) {
            constraints.remove(constraint);
        }
    }
    if (result.size() == n) {
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println("Unsatisfied constraints: " + remainingConstraints);
```

You can implement `helpsSatsfyAtLeastOne(...)` to enforce an order of constraints to satisfy if you need to prioritize some, or just have it run through the constraints in no particular order.

This is a greedy approach and you have no guarantee that the end result will be 100% perfect. If some constraints remain unsatisfied at the end, then try to enforce precedence in the constraints.

### tl;dr

This approach is simple and should give you *good enough* results most of the time. If it doesn't and your data set is so specific that you need a more exact solution, then there is more work to do. But I assume this is not the case, since you just want a nice set of diverse elements on a webpage.

1. Quantify what it means to satisfy your constraints (in terms of
   cardinality, relative/absolute number of elements representing a
   column, etc.)
2. Iterate on your references by decreasing order of date (most recent
   first)
3. Each item has a probability `p` of being chosen

   1. If an item is chosen (with the probability process), check if adding
      it to the result contributes to at least one constraint (i.e: does
      it increase the number of `someColumn`?). If so, add it to the
      result.
   2. Then check if some constraints are satisfied now that this element
      is added (i.e "Do I have *enough* of `someColumn` in my result
      set?"). Remove those constraints.
4. If all constraints are satisfied but you can still add elements to your set, then add some at random on in whichever fashion you like.